# itunes Store sign in in app purchase text clipped. There's nothing I can do about this, right?

Tags: iphone, ios

This is coming from iTunes connect. There's nothing I can do about the clipped text, right?

[image: In app purchase cut off]

Comment: If you mean to solve that with code, please include the relevant code. Otherwise, I think this is more suited for [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: I don't think so, that dialog is owned by iOS, not a lot you can do code-wise to resolve it.

Comment: That definitely looks like a bug to me. File a radar with Apple.

Comment: Yeah, it's what I figured. Is it likely because the app is locked in landscape? I don't buy too many in app purchases, and of the apps I do have, it's portrait.